# DomPDF: Image not readable or empty

Tags: php, html, pdf, laravel, dompdf

For some reason, DomPDF won't render an image included in the html that is being parsed:

[image: PDF Image missing]

However, the image is rendered on the page when it is returned as html:

[image: HTML Image exists]

I've looked at these issues and have make sure that DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE is set to true and verified file permissions:
[dompdf image not real image not readable or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543796/dompdf-image-not-real-image-not-readable-or-empty)
[Image error in DOMPDF for ZF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724442/image-error-in-dompdf-for-zf2/23745381#23745381)

Are there any other things that I should be checking for?

Comment: Is the PHP setting `allow_url_fopen` set to true? If you're using 0.6.x you can load dompdf/www/setup.php to see if there are any red marks in your install.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Following helped me like charm, at least localy, and even with

```
define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", false);
```

The solution is to change the image SRC to the absolute path on the server, like this:

```
<img src="/var/www/domain/images/myimage.jpg" />
```

All of the following worked for me:

```
<img src="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/placeholder.jpg';?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'\placeholder.jpg';?>"/>
<img src="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'./placeholder.jpg';?>"/>
```

$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] is C:/wamp/www/ZendSkeletonApplication/public

[Thanks to this: lost in code](http://www.lost-in-code.com/programming/php-code/dompdf-images-not-working/)

Comment: Converting the image to base64 works for me

```$imageUrl = (string) Image::make(public_path($path))
                ->fit(80, 80)
                ->encode('data-url');```

Comment: Adding absolute path worked for me instead relative path.

Comment: Your define statement didn't work. This works for me: $dompdf = new Dompdf(array('enable_remote' => true)); (from Jon's answer)

Answer (score 33):

As there was another answer that suggests enabling the remote option in `module.config.php` and I can't yet add comments, I thought it would be best to answer that this file does not exist in newer versions of DomPDF.

If you need to include remotely stored images in a newer version you have to pass it as an option to the constructor:

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf(array('enable_remote' => true));
```

This fixed the issue I had.

Comment: `enable_remote` has synonyms, mentioned in https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/src/Options.php:  `elseif($key === 'isRemoteEnabled' || $key === 'is_remote_enabled' || $key === 'enable_remote') {$this->setIsRemoteEnabled($value);}`

Comment: This turned out to work well. `$dompdf = new Dompdf();` `$dompdf->set_option("enable_remote", true);`

Answer (score 15):

Ok
I had the same problem with image using :

```
<img id="logo" src="/images/flags/fr.png" width="50" alt="Logo">
```

But if I add a . before /images, without changing anything in dompdf_config.custom.inc, it works

```
<img id="logo" src="./images/flags/fr.png" width="50" alt="Logo">
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The reason that worked is because originally you are looking for the images directory in the root. The "./" just means "look in this directory". You could actually remove the "./" and it will still work.

Comment: you rule. I was about to rearrange a lot of stuff!!

Comment: After all these try I gave... this is the solution!

Answer (score 12):

You can use base64 encoded image

```
<img src="{{'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents(@$image))}}" alt="image" >
```

Comment: Thanks, Mate. I was trying to get an image from S3 to display in the PDF. Worked like a charm for me 

Answer (score 11):

Now (May 2018) the correct way is :

```
$options = new Options();
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled',true);      
$dompdf = new Dompdf( $options );
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't really need `isRemoteEnabled` turned on, if all your images and what not are on the same server that executes the script.

### Why it doesn't load your image

DomPdf protects you from being attacked through it. As per [documentation](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#referencing-resources-like-images) the following won't work:

```php
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->getOptions()->getChroot(); // something like 'C:\\laragon\\www\\your-local-website\\vendor\\dompdf\\dompdf'

$html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <img src="C:\\laragon\\www\\your-local-website\\public\\img\\logo.png">
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
```

You should change CHROOT to your desired absolute path with

```php
$dompdf->getOptions()->setChroot("C:\\laragon\\www\\your-local-website\\public");
```

and then you can insert any `<img>` with `src` from within (can be nested) that `/public` folder into HTML.

#### Security note

It seems like an easy win to just set Chroot to your app root folder, but **don't**. It opens up a nasty gate, one you want to keep shut. Supposedly there are no critical scripts in `/public`, only images, public documents, routing etc.

#### Usage note

Note that I used a different directory separator than the one being used in documentation. I *believe* the best practice would be to do something in lines of:

```php
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

$public = ABSPATH . DS . 'public'; // ABSPATH is defined to be __DIR__ in root folder of your app
$image = $public . DS . 'logo' . DS . 'logo-md.png';

/* Optional */
$saveLocation = ABSPATH . DS . '..' . DS . 'private' . DS . 'invoices'; // Note that save location doesn't have to be in '/public' (or even in 'www')

$html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                font-family: DejaVu Sans !important;
            }
            @page {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
                min-height: 100%;
                padding: 0;
            }          
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="{$image}">
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->getOptions()->setChroot($public);
$domPdf->loadHtml($html, 'UTF-8');
$domPdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$domPdf->render();

/* either */
$domPdf->stream($filename); // filename is optional

/* or */
$outputString = $domPdf->output();
$pdfFile = fopen($saveLocation, 'w');
fwrite($pdfFile, $outputString);
fclose($pdfFile);
```

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem by using external CSS's full path. This one worked on my linux ubuntu server :

`<link href="{{ public_path('css/style.css') }}" />`

`<img src="{{ public_path('images/image.jpg') }}" />`

and work on image.

Comment: When providing sample code, please provide it as an example to fix the problem for the asker.  (IE Sample code with a full path to an image rather than a stylesheet since this question is about an image.)

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions here worked for me. Instead I just base64 encoded the image and then it worked. You can use this [tool](https://www.base64-image.de/).

Comment: Same with . None of the solutions worked. At the last tried base64 thanks to this comment and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For our use case we had to convert all the images on the page to base64 since the pdf should be usable offline. Our code lives inside a controller class but you can modify that to your needs.

Here's the code:

```
    /**
     * Convert images to Base64 so it's included in the PDF.
     *
     * @param $html  Full html render of the page.
     */
    public function convertReportImagesToURI($html): string
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc->loadHTML($html);
        $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
        $imgArr = array();

        // Iterate over all image tags.
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            // Get the src attribute.
            $imgSrc = $tag->getAttribute('src');

            // Convert to base64.
            $base64src = self::getImageDataURI($imgSrc);
            $tag->setAttribute('src', $base64src);
        }
        return $doc->saveHTML();
    }

    /**
     * This does the actual encoding.
     */
    public static function getImageDataURI($image, $mime = ''): string
    {
        // Director::absoluteURL('/') gets the base url of the site.
        // We had to remove the leading slash of the image hence the use of substr.
        // If your images have absolute urls you will need to modify this.
        $imageLocation = Director::absoluteURL('/') . substr($image, 1);
        // Get the image location. remove leading slash on image url.
        return 'data:' . self::get_image_mime_type($imageLocation) . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($imageLocation));
    }

    /**
     * https://stackoverflow.com/a/45054843
     * @param $image_path
     * @return string
     */
    public static function get_image_mime_type($image_path): string
    {
        $mimes  = array(
            IMAGETYPE_GIF => "image/gif",
            IMAGETYPE_JPEG => "image/jpg",
            IMAGETYPE_PNG => "image/png",
            IMAGETYPE_SWF => "image/swf",
            IMAGETYPE_PSD => "image/psd",
            IMAGETYPE_BMP => "image/bmp",
            IMAGETYPE_TIFF_II => "image/tiff",
            IMAGETYPE_TIFF_MM => "image/tiff",
            IMAGETYPE_JPC => "image/jpc",
            IMAGETYPE_JP2 => "image/jp2",
            IMAGETYPE_JPX => "image/jpx",
            IMAGETYPE_JB2 => "image/jb2",
            IMAGETYPE_SWC => "image/swc",
            IMAGETYPE_IFF => "image/iff",
            IMAGETYPE_WBMP => "image/wbmp",
            IMAGETYPE_XBM => "image/xbm",
            IMAGETYPE_ICO => "image/ico");

        if (($image_type = exif_imagetype($image_path))
            && (array_key_exists($image_type, $mimes))) {
            return $mimes[$image_type];
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when loading local images and figured out that

```
$dompdf->getOptions()->setChroot($path_to_images);
```

was not enough, I additionally had to set

```
chdir($path_to_images);
```

Answer (score -1):

In path :

> vendor/dino/dompdf-module/config/module.config.php

change settings

> enable_remote' => false,

то true.

Comment: For newer versions the way you specify this setting has apparently changed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362099/405015