# DomPdf rendering black and white image

Tags: php, laravel, image, pdf, dompdf

I am creating a pdf file with dompdf.  In the file is a logo .png image with background transparent.  When the file is created it renders the image background black and foreground white. Which is not correct.  Can someone help to rectify this?

```
    public function downloadPdf($id)
      {
        $application = FertilAppUser::application($id);
        $schedule = FertilAppUser::schedule($id);
        $fertiluser = FertilAppUser::detail($id);

        $publicPath = public_path('/');
        $view = false;

        // Generate file name
        $filename = $this->makeSafe($application[0]->fname . '_' . $application[0]->bname);
        
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.fertil.schedule.pdf', compact('application', 'schedule', 'fertiluser', 'view'))->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
        return $pdf->download($filename . '_Bemesting_Skedule.pdf');
    }
```

Here is the pdf html image path:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" alt="Logo" style="width: 120px; height:66px;"/>
```

I also tried `public_path('images/logo.png')` and `'./images/logo.png'`.  This did not work.  I also tried using a .jpg file with alpha channel removed with no change in rendering a color photo.

What is strange though is that on my localhost the image is rendered correctly but on my shared hosting provider's server this incorrect image rendering persists.
When I logOutputFile it gives:

```
<span style='color: #000' title='Frames'>   242</span><span style='color: #009' title='Memory'>  20480.00 KB</span><span style='color: #900' title='Time'>    233.81 ms</span><span  title='Quirksmode'>  <span style='color: #d00'> ON</span></span><br />
```

Comment: Try hardcoding the full folder path for the image. /var/www/vhosts/subfolder_names/logo.png, or C:/xampp/htdocs/subfolder_names/logo.png or http://yoursite.com/subfolder_names/logo.png. if works one you can do something.

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe Thanks for your comment.  I tried the full path with https and www for `mysite.com/images/logo.png`.  It is still rendering a black and white logo.  Do you know anything else I can try?

Comment: Your solution works if I use the .jpg file with the alpha channel removed.  I also noticed that the .jpg file I used earlier had transparent parts.  So I created a new image and explicitly removed the alpha channel, copied it to the `public_path` and `asset` path.  Now it renders colour.  It seems the main problem is that the domPdf engine cannot render transparency.

Comment: this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558449/dompdf-image-not-readable-or-empty